# Identical SQL...but phpmyadmin is fast while php is slow?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple query that checks for an id and typically returns no results.

On phpmyadmin this query executes roughly at: 0.0004 seconds.  On the php server and as mysqli command it takes on average.1 seconds.  This is significant for what I'm doing and I would like to close the gap.

It's not a cache issue...as nocaching the query in phpmyadmin still runs fast.

Is this the fault of Mysqli?

Now...phpmyadmin is on the database server, while the webserver is a separate machine.  The webserver does connect to an IP and not a domain name though (no need for resolution).

Could persistent connections help?

Ideas for what could be the problem?

--

Example Query:

```
select kitchen_id from kitchen_options where kitchen_appliance = 3.
```

So very small...18 row table.  `kitchen_id` is an int.  Typically no results.

Still slow :(  But phpMyAdmin is fast...

Comment: So phpmyadmin is on the localhost of the mysql server and the http server isn't?  Well there is your answer right there.

Comment: @lad2025 The post has been updated with the query.

Comment: @Flosculus Yes...separate servers.  This still seems extreme.  Are there any other ways to diagnose and fix the bottleneck?  I'm not sure if I can merge the servers for production.

Comment: @user2662680 Try running the same query twice.  If it takes around the same amount of time, you should look into your network configuration.  Poor DNS caching is a common culprit where I work.

Comment: @Flosculus Running twice doesn't help.  Also, the connection goes to the IP directly...so shouldn't there be no issue with dns caching?

Comment: Running twice wasn't supposed to help.  It was supposed to test if the problem is "connection" or "packet loss", as for DNS issues, thats just an example of what "I've" had to deal with.  Your problem, although probably not DNS, is highly likely to be network related.

Comment: What is the result if you add "Explain"?